How do i create web only application using create-expo-app?
I just tried to create a web application, I'm familiar with react-native so I intent to use expo as react-native-web recommendation but I don't see any statement to create expo web only.
Is create-expo-app support init web only?

There is no such thing, the whole point of Expo is to build a universal app that runs on Android, iOS and web.

@user18309290 if so, how do i remove Android and iOS related package from expo? I want to make it as simple as possible so I don't need unnecessary package that installed in package.json

Here is a clear explanation of how you can create a web-only application using create-expo-app:
https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/web/

I've read it but I think the doc only show how to integrate it
